# WPF ListBox item with ContextMenu click event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm trying to handle click event on the context menu of the ListBoxItem.
The XAML code is:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LB_TranslationResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="254,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteItem" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

The DeleteItem event looks like:

```
private void DeleteItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

Strange, but this event does not work. Context menu appears, but when I click on it's item nothing happens.

Can you tell, please, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Hope it's just a typo. In XAML code handler name is `DeleteItem` and in code behind its name is `DeleteTranslation`.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I've renamed it to DeleteItem to make it more clear for this post. So this is not the reasont

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the event handler for the *Click* event into a style and use an [EventSetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for invoking your code behind event handler:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LB_TranslationResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="254,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DeleteItemContextMenuStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DeleteItem"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteItemContextMenuStyle}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```